Seeing odd behavior attempting to add PCF to shadow map shader
I've been working recently to improve our in-game shadows by attempting to fix a few self-shadowing issues and jagged edges. One of the improvements I've attempted to add is PCF to make our shadows a little less blocky. However, when attempting to implement this I'm seeing very unexpected behavior and I'm having issues figuring out exactly what is going on.
This first image shows the shader before attempting any PCF. This is the shader we've been using for a while and it generally works, minus the obviously jagged edges along the side of the level and some improper shading on the tree stump.

This second image shows what happens attempting to use PCF. I don't believe it's the PCF function as it's basically pulled directly from working example, but I could definitely be wrong.

Here is my shader code (HLSL):
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  VARIABLES
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
matrix World;
matrix WorldViewProjection;

float3 AmbientLightColor;

////Be sure this matches the define in SolariDefines.cs
//static const int MAX_POINT_LIGHTS = 8;
//int PointLightCount;
//float3 PointLightPosition[MAX_POINT_LIGHTS];
//float PointLightRange[MAX_POINT_LIGHTS];
//float3 PointLightColor[MAX_POINT_LIGHTS];
//

float3 DirectionalLight;
float3 DirectionalLightColor;
float DirectionalLightIntensity;
float4x4 xLightsWorldViewProjection;

texture Texture;
sampler TextureSampler = sampler_state
{
    texture = <Texture>;
    magfilter = LINEAR;
    minfilter = LINEAR;
    mipfilter = LINEAR;
    AddressU = mirror;
    AddressV = mirror;
};

texture Normals;
sampler NormalMapSampler = sampler_state
{
    texture = (Normals);
    MagFilter = LINEAR;
    MinFilter = LINEAR;
    Mipfilter = LINEAR;
};

texture ShadowMap;
sampler ShadowMapSampler = sampler_state 
{
    texture = <ShadowMap>; 
    magfilter = LINEAR; 
    minfilter = LINEAR;
    mipfilter = LINEAR;
    AddressU = clamp; 
    AddressV = clamp; 
};

float DepthBias;
float ShadowMapSize = 2048;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  STRUCTS
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float3 Normal: NORMAL0;
    float2 texCoord     : TEXCOORD0;

    float3 Binormal : BINORMAL0;
    float3 Tangent : TANGENT0;
};

struct SMapVertexToPixel
{
    float4 Position     : POSITION;
    float Depth    : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct SMapPixelToFrame
{
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
};

struct SSceneVertexToPixel
{
    float4 Position             : POSITION;
    float4 Pos2DAsSeenByLight    : TEXCOORD0;

    float2 TexCoords            : TEXCOORD1;
    float3 Normal                : TEXCOORD2;
    float4 Position3D            : TEXCOORD3;

    float3x3 WorldToTangentSpace : TEXCOORD4;
};

struct SScenePixelToFrame
{
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  HELPER FUNCTIONS
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
float GetVariableBias(float nDotL)
{
    return clamp( 0.005 * tan(acos(nDotL)), 0, DepthBias );
}

float CalcShadowTermPCF(float linearDepthLV, float ndotl, float2 shadowTexCoord)
{
    float lightTerm = 0;

    float2 fractionals = frac(ShadowMapSize * shadowTexCoord);

    float size = 1.0f / ShadowMapSize;
    float variableBias = GetVariableBias(ndotl);
    float testDepth = linearDepthLV - variableBias;

    //Center
    lightTerm = (linearDepthLV < tex2D(ShadowMapSampler, shadowTexCoord).r);

    //Right
    lightTerm += (testDepth < tex2D(ShadowMapSampler, shadowTexCoord + float2(size, 0)).r) * fractionals.x;

    //Left
    lightTerm += (testDepth < tex2D(ShadowMapSampler, shadowTexCoord + float2(-size, 0)).r) * (1 - fractionals.x);

    //Top
    lightTerm += (testDepth < tex2D(ShadowMapSampler, shadowTexCoord + float2(0, size)).r) * fractionals.y;

    //Bottom
    lightTerm += (testDepth < tex2D(ShadowMapSampler, shadowTexCoord + float2(0, -size)).r) * (1 - fractionals.y);

    lightTerm /= 3;
    return lightTerm;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  VERTEX / PIXEL FUNCTIONS
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
SMapVertexToPixel ShadowMapVertexShader(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    SMapVertexToPixel Output = (SMapVertexToPixel)0;

    Output.Position = mul(input.Position, xLightsWorldViewProjection);
    Output.Depth = Output.Position.z / Output.Position.w;

    return Output;
}

SMapPixelToFrame ShadowMapPixelShader(SMapVertexToPixel PSIn)
{
    SMapPixelToFrame Output = (SMapPixelToFrame)0;
    Output.Color = float4( PSIn.Depth, PSIn.Depth, PSIn.Depth, PSIn.Depth );
    return Output;
}

SSceneVertexToPixel ShadowedSceneVertexShader(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    SSceneVertexToPixel Output = (SSceneVertexToPixel)0;

    Output.Position = mul(input.Position, WorldViewProjection);
    Output.Pos2DAsSeenByLight = mul(input.Position, xLightsWorldViewProjection);
    Output.Normal = normalize(mul(input.Normal, (float3x3)World));
    Output.Position3D = mul(input.Position, World);
    Output.TexCoords = input.texCoord;

    Output.WorldToTangentSpace[0] = mul(normalize(input.Tangent), World);
    Output.WorldToTangentSpace[1] = mul(normalize(input.Binormal), World);
    Output.WorldToTangentSpace[2] = mul(normalize(input.Normal), World);

    return Output;
}

SScenePixelToFrame ShadowedScenePixelShader(SSceneVertexToPixel PSIn)
{
    SScenePixelToFrame Output = (SScenePixelToFrame)0;

    float2 shadowMapTexCoords;
    shadowMapTexCoords[0] = PSIn.Pos2DAsSeenByLight.x / PSIn.Pos2DAsSeenByLight.w / 2.0f + 0.5f;
    shadowMapTexCoords[1] = -PSIn.Pos2DAsSeenByLight.y / PSIn.Pos2DAsSeenByLight.w / 2.0f + 0.5f;

    float diffuseLightingFactor = 0;

    float3 normalMap = 2.0 *(tex2D(NormalMapSampler, PSIn.TexCoords)) - 1.0;
    float3 normal = normalize(mul(normalMap, PSIn.WorldToTangentSpace));

    float depthStoredInShadowMap = tex2D(ShadowMapSampler, shadowMapTexCoords).r;
    float realDistance = PSIn.Pos2DAsSeenByLight.z / PSIn.Pos2DAsSeenByLight.w;
    float nDotL = dot(-DirectionalLight, normal);
    float variableBias = GetVariableBias( nDotL );

    if ( (realDistance - variableBias) <= depthStoredInShadowMap )
    {
        //diffuseLightingFactor = saturate(nDotL);
        //diffuseLightingFactor *= DirectionalLightIntensity;

        //TODO - Why does this cause erroneous self-shadowing?
        float shadowContribution = CalcShadowTermPCF( realDistance, nDotL, shadowMapTexCoords );
        diffuseLightingFactor = DirectionalLightIntensity * shadowContribution;
    }

    float4 texColor = tex2D(TextureSampler, PSIn.TexCoords);
    float3 finalLighting = DirectionalLightColor * diffuseLightingFactor + AmbientLightColor;
    Output.Color = texColor * float4( finalLighting, 1.0f );

    return Output;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  TECHNIQUES
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
technique ShadowMap
{
    pass P0
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_4_0 ShadowMapVertexShader();
        PixelShader = compile ps_4_0 ShadowMapPixelShader();
    }
}

technique ShadowedScene
{
    pass P0
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_4_0 ShadowedSceneVertexShader();
        PixelShader = compile ps_4_0 ShadowedScenePixelShader();
    }
}





And finally, a snippet of my C# code in which I set up the directional light's view and projection matrices. The CalculateDirectionalLightProjection function is used for dynamically creating a projection frustum based on the size of the level's bounding box. I have not included it as I see the same results when using the commented out line where I simply hard code the values.
private void UpdateLightData()
        {
            //Directional Light / Ortho
            Matrix lightsView = Matrix.CreateLookAt( -_LightDirection, new Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ), Vector3.Up );
            //Matrix lightsProjection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter( -20f, 20f, -20f, 20f, -30f, 30f );

            BoundingBox boundingBox = GetBoundingBox( levelModel );
            Matrix lightsProjection = CalculateDirectionalLightProjection( boundingBox, _LightDirection );

            lightsViewProjectionMatrix = lightsView * lightsProjection;
        }

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! I've been messing with this for a few days and have not been able to determine if the bug lies within my attempt to add PCF or there is something wrong in the core shader calculations.
